# Find the first printf format sequence in a C++ string

Tags: c++, c, algorithm, c++11, printf

I search the most concise and efficient way to find the first  `printf` format sequence (conversion specification) in a C++ string (I cannot use `std::regex` as they are not yet implement in most in compilers).

So the problem is to write an optimized function that will return the beginning of the first `printf`-format sequence `pos` and its length `n` from an input string `str`:

```
inline void detect(const std::string& str, int& pos, int& n);
```

For example, for:

- `%d` **->** `pos = 0` and `n = 2`
- `the answer is: %05d` **->** `pos = 15` and `n = 4`
- `the answer is: %% %4.2f haha` **->** `pos = 18` and `n = 5`

How to do that (clever and tricky ways are welcome)?

Comment: Why not just grab an open-source `printf` implementation and rip the parser bits out of it?

Comment: You don't need regexes. The printf format specifier format can be parsed in a single pass from left to right, one character at a time.

Comment: If you look at the full POSIX specification for [`printf()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fprintf.html) formats, there are an awful lot of characters that can appear in a format specification.  For example, `%100$#+-0 '*101$.*102$llX` could be 'valid', though some of the combinations of flags are not meaningful.

Comment: Even though you don't need an argument to process `%%`, you still need to process it.

Comment: Is there a naive algorithm to the problem you can describe in plain English?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Scan forward for `%`, then parse the content from there. There are some quirky ones, but not THAT bad (not sure you want to make it an `inline` tho').

General principle (I'm just typing as I go along, so probably not the BEST form of code ever written - and I haven't tried to compile it at all).

```
inline void detect(const std::string& str, int& pos, int& n)
{
    std::string::size_type last_pos = 0;
    for(;;)
    {
         last_pos = str.find('%', last_pos)
         if (last_pos == std::string::npos)
             break;    // Not found anythin. 
         if (last_pos == str.length()-1) 
             break;     // Found stray '%' at the end of the string. 
         char ch = str[last_pos+1];

         if (ch == '%')   // double percent -> escaped %. Go on for next. 
         {
             last_pos += 2;
             continue;
         }
         pos = last_pos; 
         do 
         {
             if (isdigit(ch)) || ch == '.' || ch == '-' || ch == '*' ||
                 ch == '+' || ch == 'l' || ch == 'L' || ch == 'z' || 
                 ch == 'h' || ch == 't' || ch == 'j' || ch == ' ' || 
                 ch == '#' || ch == '\'')
             {
                last_pos++;
                ch = str[last_pos+1]; 
             }
             else
             {
                 // The below string may need appending to depending on version
                 // of printf.  
                 if (string("AacdeEfFgGiopusxX").find(ch) != std::string::npos)
                 {
                     // Do something about invalid string? 
                 }
                 n = last_pos - pos; 
                 return; 
              }
         } while (last_pos < str.length()); 
     }
 }
```

edit2: This bit is probably better written as:

```
             if (isdigit(ch)) || ch == '.' || ch == '-' || ch == '*' ||
                 ch == '+' || ch == 'l' || ch == 'L' || ch == 'z' || 
                 ch == 'h' || ch == 't' || ch == 'j' || ch == ' ' || 
                 ch == '#' || ch == '\'') ... 

 if (string("0123456789.-*+lLzhtj #'").find(ch) != std::string::npos) ...
```

Now, that's your homework done. please report back with what grade you get.

Edit: It should be noted that some things that a regular printf will "reject" is accepted by the above code, e.g. "%.......5......6f", "%5.8d", "%-5-6d" or "%-----09---5555555555555555llllld". If you want the code to reject these sort of things, it's not a huge amount of extra work, just need a little bit of logic to check "have we seen this character before" in the "check for special characters or digit", and in most cases the special character should only be allowed once. And as the comment says, I may have missed a couple of valid format specifiers. It gets further trickier if you also need to cope with "this 'l' is not allowed with 'c'" or such rules. But if the input isn't "malicious" (e.g. you want to annotate where on which line there are format specifiers in a working C source file), the above should work reasonably well.

Comment: `h` is a length modifier (like `L` and `l`) as are `j` and `t`. Both space and `#` are flags; in POSIX 2008, `'` is a flag too. You seem to have missed `A`, `a`, `E`, `F`, `g`, `G`, `i` as conversion specifiers.  `z` is a length modifier rather than a conversion specifier, so there needs to be conversion specifier after `z`. POSIX supports `5$` etc to specify arguments by position. Actually validating this stuff is actually quite hard work, as opposed to accepting sequences of characters that might be legitimate. Whether that's necessary depends on what else you're going to do.

Comment: Ok, I just did it without looking it up, so I suppose could have been worse. I have updated with the extra ones you mentioned and moved the `z` around. And yes, validating to complete certainty seemed to be more than a bit tricky, so I just decided for "is it something that might be a valid format specifier".

Comment: I have just over 400 lines of code (excluding comments and test program) that parses a `printf()` format string into a structure, or converts one of the structures into a format string.  I didn't show it because it is just too long for SO.  And it's C code, not C++ code.

Comment: Yes, that seems a bit excessive as a an answer to this question - unless you have a real need to do exactly that, of course. 400 lines isn't that excessive if it's a complete parser for format strings, I'd say. Sounds pretty neat.

Comment: In other words, you have a fully flying Cessna aeroplane, I've posted something along a paper-glider...

Comment: Perhaps not quite that exaggerated a difference (paper glider versus balsa model Cessna, perhaps), but yes.  And, as you say, overkill for the answer to this question.  If someone has a need of it, they can contact me — see my profile.